# Line break the list element in Python

Tags: python, django, list

How do I display all the elements in a list with a line break in a Django template? 
For example, with a list
`ls = ['bin', 'boot', 'data', 'data2']` I would like to display the elements in the format

```
bin
boot
data
data2
```

I have tried:

```
'\n'.join(ls)
```

This returns each word with spaces:

```
b i n b o o t d a t a d a t a 2
```

The relevant code from my views.py:

```
   result1 = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/home/zurelsoft/R'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        result = ''.join(result1)
        return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'res':result, 'res1':command}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The corresponding section of the template:

```
<td>{{ res }} </td>
```

Comment: do you want the output like: a (line no. 1) b(line no. 2) and so on.

Comment: "want to display the elements" -- where? On your terminal? Window? HTML page?

Comment: HTML PAGE(in a Django template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your view to use the `splitlines()` function to split the output into a list of lines:

```
def myview(request):
    result = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/home/zurelsoft/R'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].splitlines()
    return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'res':result, 'res1':command}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And then use the [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join) filter in your template to separate each element in the list with the HTML line-break tag `<br />`:

```
<td>{{ res|join:"<br/>" }}</td>
```

Comment: For clarity, the string.join(list) syntax compounds the elements of list with string sticking them together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am trying to achieve this result in Django. Instead of line break I get spaces: o t s b i n s e l i n u x s r v s y s t m p u p l o a d u s r v a r

Comment: @sachitad - you mean in a Django template? Could you please update your question with an example showing the full problem, its hard to answer questions without knowing the details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use join with a `newline (\n)`: -

```
'\n'.join(ls);  // This will only work for list of strings.
```

or simply use a `for loop` to iterate over your list, and print each element: -

```
for elem in ls: 
    print elem
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'\n'.join(ls)
```

`"\n"` is a special character meaning "line break".

Answer (score 2):

If res is a list, then you can loop through the list and output each element in its own  tag.

```
{% for r in res %}
  <td>{{ r }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you remove the """result = ''.join(result1)""" line of code, this should work, but no matter since you've already accepted an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> out=reduce(lambda x, y: x+y+'\n', ls, "" )
>>> print out
a
b
c
d
e
```

`join` calls reduce to accumulate the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'\n'.join(ls)
```

It gives a list with elements separated with 'next line'. In your first example your tried '' which is an empty sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in ls:
    print "%s"%i
```

This will give you the desired output.